# how to use placeholder for Textbox in VB.Net 2010 like html

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that does some mathematical calculation.

I want to be able users to enter data quickly without erasing the value.

I thing its good to use placeholder like I did in html

but how can i use it in VB.Net 2010?
Thanks

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        gtp.Text = "0.00"
        vatt.Text = "0.00"
        wht.Text = "0.00"
        npr.Text = "0.00"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code clears the text box if the current value is the placeholder value, otherwise it retains the input value.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
    If TextBox1.Text = "0.00" Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0.00"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If you always want it to clear the textbox then use this.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0.00"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

To simulate an actual placeholder such as the one in HTML5 you'll need to overlay a `label` control on top of your textbox and set it's visability based on the event `keyDown` and `LostFocus`/`Leave` Event which will depend on your version of VS

Comment: I was looking at a way to clear the textbox when you start typing, but I ran out of time. You could either set a first keystroke flag and retain the keystroke or select all upon entering the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I created DLL for this work.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmR1BM6vUcAGgYsLPvjrec0Z92OTlQ

Or you can download the project PlaceHolder class

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmR1BM6vUcAGgYsMNFGbtW5HL_4Ifw

How to use?

In your winform project add the DLL.

(I added groupbox for this example)

CS Code:

```
var textBoxWithPlaceHolder = new Placeholder.PlaceholderTextBox();
textBoxWithPlaceHolder.PlaceholderText = "Search text";
textBoxWithPlaceHolder.Location  = new Point(x: 10, y: 20);
GBTextBox.Controls.Add(textBoxWithPlaceHolder);
```

Result winform

[image]